# 'Code edited on answer' looks way too big (and doesn't sound right!)

Tags: bug, design, stackexchange.com, network-profile

In the network profile, on the inbox tab, the `Code edited on answer` looks too big to fit in the box, spanning *4* lines! Could the column width be increased? At least to bring the 'on' onto the same line as 'answer':

> [image]

It looks fine in the top bar inbox though (if you're interested):

> [image]

---

Whilst we're there - is:

> code edited on answer

correct? I *think* it would be more correct to say:

> code edited ***in*** answer

---

Oh, and by the way, when was this added? I've never seen it say something like this before! (Probably because nobody ever edited code blocks in my answers...)